# Minecraft alpha, beta, indev, infdev, classic, all do not work

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I have had this problem for around 2 years now, and I just can't figure out how to fix it.
Basically, whenever I try to play old versions of minecraft (Don't judge me, I enjoy it.) they all will crash when I don't have fullscreen on, or some like indev still will crash even when I DO have fullscreen on. Beta and alpha don't crash necessarily, but just lock all keyboard input.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I wonder if that's a new development or did they crash the same when leaving fullscreen back in the day they were released... Minecraft was never (and still isn't) very graceful toggling windowed/fullscreen, I'd be unsurprised if back then it was completely broken.

Comment: Some versions don't even HAVE fullscreen. I have a mac, and windows users don't seem to be having this problem.